# How to create a non-root logger in python

Tags: python, logging, handler, root

I'm trying to create a non-root logger in a child python module using logging.getLogger('child'), but I'm getting an error "No handlers could be found for logger "child"

I'm trying to have a parent module log to parent log file. The parent module will create instances of the child module, and I want the child module to write its own child log file, without propagating its messages up to the parent log file.

Here's what I have for the parent module (this is executed by the user):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging, child

logging.basicConfig( filename='parent.log' )
logging.warning( 'test log from parent' )

c = child.run()
```

And here's the child module:

```
import logging
class run:
  def __init__(self):
    logging.basicConfig( filename = 'child.log' )
    childLogger = logging.getLogger( __name__ )
    childLogger.propagate = False
    childLogger.warning( 'this is a log from the child' )
```

Expected output is to have 2 files: parent.log (containing the 1 WARNING line from the parent module) and child.log (containing the one WARNING line from the child module).

Actual output is: one WARNING line (from the parent) is printed into the parent.log file, and there is no child.log file--the child log message isn't recorded anywhere.

Can you please tell me what I'm missing? TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='child.log')
childLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in your child module with:

```
childLogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
childLogger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('child.log'))
```

or, alternatively, use [dictConfig](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) or [fileConfig](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig) to configure logging in one place.

What's wrong with [basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)? From the docs:

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it.

So basically, your call to `basicLogging` in child module has no effect, since the first one (in parent module) has already configured the root logger. And by setting the child logger's `propagate` to `false`, the child's log entries don't get forwarded to the root logger, so you get the `No handlers could be found...` warning.

**Edit**

Just to elaborate on  [fileConfig](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig), which allows a lot of flexibility, for your modules you could create a file called `logging.ini`:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,child

[handlers]
keys=logfile,logfile_child

[formatters]
keys=default

# loggers

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=logfile

[logger_child]
level=INFO
handlers=logfile_child
qualname=child
propagate=0

# handlers

[handler_logfile]
class=FileHandler
formatter=default
args=('parent.log',)

[handler_logfile_child]
class=FileHandler
formatter=default
args=('child.log',)

# formatters

[formatter_default]
format=%(asctime)s [%(module)s:%(lineno)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Then, somewhere in your application, you would just need to call `fileConfig`:

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini')
```

This way your logging is configured in one place, which makes is easier to add additional loggers, change log levels, etc.