# Flask URL No Longer Prints in Pycharm Conscole

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pycharm

This is my first time posting a question in a .... VERY long time.

So I wrote my first Flask App maybe a month ago. I go to open the project, I click run, and the URL no longer prints in the Pycharm Console Window. Normally, I would click this URL to route to site 127.0.0.1..

The only text that prints now is ..

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
```

Any Ideas good people of the internet?

Comment: that is really weird, what is the version of your PyCharm

Comment: Can you give us a minimal example that produces the problem?

Comment: PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1

..I havent done any updates that Im aware of

Comment: This is the app.py, nothing has changed to this file or the template file ... just randomly stopped launching the local website that displays the Flask App.

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        try:
            some stuff
        except:
            error_message

        return render_template('upload.html', errors=error_message)
    return render_template('upload.html')


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Comment: Hey Good People,

So I had some import statements at the top of my code, one of them .. when removed that link displays..

These are the two statements 

from extract.LoadExcel import LoadExcel
from transform.VerifyDeductions import VerifyDeductions

The second one ... when commented or removed, the link generates as expected.

Comment: ..Im wondering if it has something to do with the logging that I have inside my code.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there an issue w/ Flask whereas you CANNOT use the Root Logger .. I had to create a Non Root Logger..

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684159/how-to-create-a-non-root-logger-in-python)